# How to avoid row names in further analysis in R?

Tags: rstudio, rows, reshape

I´m just running the following example from GGEBiplotGUI package and of course, it works properly.

```
library(GGEBiplotGUI)

data("Ontario")
Ontario

GGEBiplot(Data = Ontario)
```

But when I download "Ontario" data and I want to run the above cited script on my PC. See the example below.

```
Ontario <- read.csv("Book.csv")

library(GGEBiplotGUI)

GGEBiplot(Data = Ontario)
```

The result is the following table (from column 0 to 10) taking numbers (From 1 to 17) as genotypes and "X" as another location.

See the result below please.

```
  X  BH93  EA93  HW93  ID93  KE93  NN93  OA93  RN93  WP93
1  ann 4.460 4.150 2.849 3.084 5.940 4.450 4.351 4.039 2.672
2  ari 4.417 4.771 2.912 3.506 5.699 5.152 4.956 4.386 2.938
3  aug 4.669 4.578 3.098 3.460 6.070 5.025 4.730 3.900 2.621
4  cas 4.732 4.745 3.375 3.904 6.224 5.340 4.226 4.893 3.451
5  del 4.390 4.603 3.511 3.848 5.773 5.421 5.147 4.098 2.832
6  dia 5.178 4.475 2.990 3.774 6.583 5.045 3.985 4.271 2.776
7  ena 3.375 4.175 2.741 3.157 5.342 4.267 4.162 4.063 2.032
8  fun 4.852 4.664 4.425 3.952 5.536 5.832 4.168 5.060 3.574
9  ham 5.038 4.741 3.508 3.437 5.960 4.859 4.977 4.514 2.859
10 har 5.195 4.662 3.596 3.759 5.937 5.345 3.895 4.450 3.300
11 kar 4.293 4.530 2.760 3.422 6.142 5.250 4.856 4.137 3.149
12 kat 3.151 3.040 2.388 2.350 4.229 4.257 3.384 4.071 2.103
13 luc 4.104 3.878 2.302 3.718 4.555 5.149 2.596 4.956 2.886
14 m12 3.340 3.854 2.419 2.783 4.629 5.090 3.281 3.918 2.561
15 reb 4.375 4.701 3.655 3.592 6.189 5.141 3.933 4.208 2.925
16 ron 4.940 4.698 2.950 3.898 6.063 5.326 4.302 4.299 3.031
17 rub 3.786 4.969 3.379 3.353 4.774 5.304 4.322 4.858 3.382
```

How can I fix this problem? I mean, in order to avoid "rownames" and "x" as a variables in the GGEBiplotGUI analysis.

I have also tried with these codes and they didn´t work:

```
attributes(Ontario)$row.names <- NULL 

print(Ontario, row.names = F) 

row.names(Ontario) <- NULL 

Ontario[, -1] ## It deletes the first column not the 0 one.
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked properly.

```
Ontario <- read.csv("Libro.csv")

rownames(Ontario)<-Ontario$X  

Ontario1<-Ontario[,-1]

library(GGEBiplotGUI)

GGEBiplot(Data = Ontario)
```